# How to figure out where layout uses in project?

Tags: android, android-studio

How I can figure out in which class the particular resource file (layout/menu/ etc) called?
For example in class you could just click ctrl+left click to follow the link what is the same way with layouts?

Comment: Right-click on the file and select Find Usages.

Comment: @Deˣ also works. or alt+f7

Comment: I use Eclipse keyMap `Ctrl+G`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using android studio you can press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f7</kbd> / right click on your file <kbd>+</kbd> find usage and get this image:

[image]

You can see that `activity_main` is being used inside `MainActivity` class.